# How to allow an AppArmor path but deny rest of the subpath

Tags: linux, apparmor

I have an AppArmor profile. I have dir like

```
/home
   /nonroot
   /Documents
   /Pictures
   .
   .
   .
```

Now I want to allow only `/nonroot` path and deny rest of the path in the `/home` dir. How can I do that? Note that I have to make it generic as I don't know how many sub-dirs I may have inside the `/home`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is in fact the normal behavior of AppArmor. That is, `/home/nonroot/file.txt r,` allows reading just that file and nothing else. If you don't give permission to read `Documents`, `Pictures`, etc, then the program cannot access those.

(This is as long as you are actually enforcing the profile. Profiles can be disabled or put into complain or audit mode, which perhaps could confuse someone about how their rules are working)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to write these rules:

```
# deny anything with a name shorter than 7 chars
deny /home/?{,/} wl,
deny /home/??{,/} wl,
deny /home/???{,/} wl,
deny /home/????{,/} wl,
deny /home/?????{,/} wl,
deny /home/??????{,/} wl,

# deny anything with a name of 7 chars different to 'nonroot'
deny /home/[^n]??????{,/} wl,
deny /home/?[^o]?????{,/} wl,
deny /home/??[^n]????{,/} wl,
deny /home/???[^r]???{,/} wl,
deny /home/????[^o]??{,/} wl,
deny /home/?????[^o]?{,/} wl,
deny /home/??????[^t]{,/} wl,

# deny anything with a name longer than 7 chars
deny /home/????????*{,/} wl,
```